# Regex to get the particular values from a String

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to get the values from paragraph with regex. I tried with regex:

```
String regex =  "Are you a seller/buyer, a manufacturer, or both for the products you want to list?
ANSWER(S): s*([^,]+)"
```

The paragraph will always this substring Are you a seller/buyer, a manufacturer, or both for the products you want to list? `ANSWER(S): <interested field>`. I am looking to get the values after `:` in this question of the given paragraph.

The String after the `:` can be either one of = Both, Seller, Buyer or Manufacturer

Can some tell me what I am doing wrong ?

`:` comes in many places in the given paragraph and the string `Are you a seller/buyer, a manufacturer, or both for the products you want to list? ANSWER(S)` is going to be fixed.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what the string after the colon may look like?

Comment: Why using Regex ? you know that the result will be always be after your paragraph, why don't you use substring ? Like : `result = regex.substring(regex.indexOf(": "), regex.length())`

Comment: @GabLeg Because ':' comes in many places in the given paragraph.

Comment: What's the purpose of `s*`? Did you mean `\\s*`?

Comment: @user3407267 but is this the first time a colon is in that paragraph?

Comment: @Luca Not necessarily. Its very random.

Comment: But after this there isn't anything else?

Comment: @Luca No. Even that is random. sometimes there could be other questions like this after this. But I am interested in answer comes after the Are you a seller/buyer, a manufacturer, or both for the products you want to list? ANSWER(S):

Comment: Ohh i see, i didn't understand well what you meant. If the paragraph is well written, you could `split(". ")` then get the wanted line with comparaison then get the value with substring? Maybe not the best, just an idea.

Comment: Yeah, but if more can come after that and it's not delimited by something else, how are you going to match it?

Comment: @Luca Thats why I am  adding "Are you a seller/buyer, a manufacturer, or both for the products you want to list?
ANSWER(S):" as part of regex

Comment: I answered this question thinking it was about JavaScript, while having no idea, how to use regex in Java, it seems like I won't be able to help you

Comment: @Luca Can you post your answer ? I am looking for just the regex string not java or js

Comment: I undeleted my answer

Answer (score 2):

So, if you only want to match either `Both`, `Seller`, `Buyer` or `Manufacturer` you can use the following Regex:

```
/Are you a seller\/buyer, a manufacturer, or both for the products you want to list\? ANSWER\(S\): (Both|Seller|Buyer|Manufacturer)/
```

Here is an example usage:

```js
const re = /Are you a seller\/buyer, a manufacturer, or both for the products you want to list\? ANSWER\(S\): (Both|Seller|Buyer|Manufacturer)/;

let test = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Are you a seller/buyer, a manufacturer, or both for the products you want to list? ANSWER(S): Both lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";

console.log("The anser is: " + re.exec(test)[1]  );
```